# Spring Boot and Spring Security filter not filtering correct request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot and spring security service.
I have extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class and overridden configure method. But somehow it is not filtering correct request.

My url is something like -

```
localhost:8080/album/private/v1/getAlbumsByVendorId?vendorId=1
 localhost:8080/vendor/private/v1/getVendor?vendorId=1
```

and also I have some URL which I do not want to authenticate.like below url.

```
localhost:8080/category/v1/getCategory
```

Only want to authenticate if the URL contains private.
But seems like my filter is getting invoked for all request. 
is there something wrong in `.antMatchers("/**/private/**")`

Note - I don't have any context path as of now.
Added the classes.
Controller is just a dummy test controller.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**/private/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }
}


    @Component
    public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Autowired
        private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

            String username = null;
            String jwtToken = null;
            // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get only the Token
            if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
                try {
                    username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
                } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                    System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
                }
            } else {
                logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
            }

            //Once we get the token validate it.
            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

                UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set authentication
                if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                            .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                    // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }



@RestController
@CrossOrigin()
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping({ "/hello" })
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @RequestMapping({ "/private/test" })
    public String hello2() {
        return "Hello World-test";
    }

    @RequestMapping({ "/v1/private/test" })
    public String hello3() {
        return "Hello World-test-v1";
    }

    @RequestMapping({ "/v1/public/test" })
    public String hello4() {
        return "Hello World-test-v1-public";
    }

}
```

Comment: Added classes and a dummy controller class but my actual controller urls will be like same /v1/private/test/..... and some other urls which did not contain private and that should be open url.

Comment: All the calls are going to filter but and if wrong token getting 500 error else 401.i just want to authenticate only if the url contains /**/private/** else do not authenticate.I have so many other urls which i do not want to authenticate and only if url contains private then only authenticate it. like:8080/album/private/v1/get -- authenticate,:8080/vendor/private/v1/get -- authenticate, but in case:8080/use/v1/get -- do not authenticate,:8080/com/v1/get -- do not authenticate like this have so many urls.

Comment: As Patel Romil already wrote, you have to change `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to `.anyRequest().permitAll` (in this line). That should work.

Comment: That is just permitting all the URLs not even validating private urls

Comment: I checked it with following test: `System.out.println(new AntPathMatcher().match("/**/private/**", "/album/private/v1/get"));` results in true and `System.out.println(new AntPathMatcher().match("/**/private/**", "/use/v1/get"));`results in false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot will secure all endpoints when Spring Security is on the classpath. We need to explicitly add an exclusion for all other endpoints to be permitted without authentication. Consider change is `.anyRequest().permitAll()`,
 which means each request other than `/**/private/**` will be accessible to everyone. In other words, the filter will only apply to `/**/private/**`

[Git Link](https://github.com/romilptl/jwtSO)

*approach 1 (clean way)*

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**/private/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }
```

---

*approach 2: only check for a token if Request comes from **/private/*** *(not an ideal way)*

*JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.java*

```
@Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Entry Request: "+request.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println("Entry Contain: "+request.getRequestURI().contains("private"));
        if(request.getRequestURI().contains("private")==true) 
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");

    }
```

*JwtRequestFilter.java*

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        System.out.println("JWT Request: "+request.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println("JWT Contain: "+request.getRequestURI().contains("private"));
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        //Remove comment for second approach
        if(request.getRequestURI().contains("private")==false)
        {
            System.out.println("Do Noting, Permit It");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ") ) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

---

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/private/test **401**
```

[image: http://localhost:8080/v1/private/test]

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/public/test **200**
```

[image: http://localhost:8080/v1/public/test]

Comment: but whats about .antMatchers("/**/private/**").authenticated().right now this is also not working only it is working for .anyRequest().authenticated().Even i tried like .antMatchers("/album/**").authenticated() just to test this also did not work.Only it is working for .anyRequest().authenticated()

Comment: Hello @Rohit  `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                     .antMatchers("/**/private/**")..anyRequest().authenticated()` is working correct?

Comment: No it is not at all working. Only if .anyRequest().authenticated().and() is working fine for all the request but seems like .antMatchers("/**/private/**") is not working at all.More over i think antMatchers it self not working. for url  localhost:8080/vendor/private/v1/getVendor?vendorId=1
i tried .antMatchers("/vendor/**") this is also not working.Not sure why antMatchers it self not working properly.

Comment: Are you storing the roles of users? if yes then you can use it here

Comment: right now no roles and more over it is only working for .anyRequest().authenticated()

Comment: I have updated my answer try on it and let me know the outcome

Comment: Hi Patel, Thanks but same issue.You have added .anyRequest().authenticated() so only it is authenticating all the urls even which do not have  /**/private/** as well.But i just want to authenticate only if the url contains /**/private/** else do not authenticate.I have so many other urls which i do not want to authenticate and only if url contains private then only authenticate it. like:8080/album/private/v1/get  -- authenticate,:8080/vendor/private/v1/get  -- authenticate, but in case:8080/use/v1/get  -- do not authenticate,:8080/com/v1/get  -- do not authenticate like this have so many urls

Comment: Hi @Rohit change `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to `.anyRequest().permitAll() ` so that request which  has `private` in endPoint only need to be authenticated and other will be permited to all

Comment: Not working correctly.Now it is not even authenticating for /**/private/** . Is there anything wrong in my antMatchers.My url is @RequestMapping({ "/vendor/private/v1/get" })

Comment: You can try https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt to download sample project.In end you will get a link to download the complete code.From here i took reference and doing it.Just add few more methods in controller to simulate my test cases.It is a working spring boot code.Just import it and add few more urls in contolller and test it.You will come to know.The exact same way i have implemented even i added few urls in this code base controller and it is also not working.exact same issue like mine.

Comment: Hello @Rohit  I have tested on it and above security, config is working fine. I have provided a link of working example and let me know the outcome

Comment: Hello @Romail, Many thanks for your help. approach 1 (clean way) is not working but approach 2 is working fine. The screenshot you have attached from approach 1 or approach 2 ? How you tested approach 1 ? and idea why .antMatchers("/**/private/**").authenticated() is not working.

Comment: Hello @Rohit, I have tested on both approach and both are giving the same result. Have you tried with the git project which I have mentioned

Comment: Hello @Romail, Very sorry , Both approach is working fine.Many Many thanks.But just curious to know what was the fix.I am not able to find it out.The same approach (approach 1) have tried yesterday but it did not work.So just want to know how you fixed it.Any additional jars or anything you did for approach 1.Please tell me.

Comment: Welcome @Rohit, No I have not added any dependency or jars in it except dev tools which is for faster startup. the only thing which is different after adding 
`.anyRequest().permitAll()` ,  `addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)` instead of `.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)` which I had accidentally wrriten.

Comment: Hello, @Rohit please accept and vote up the answer so that future readers can understand which solution has been worked for you. Thank you

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded.Am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Hello Rohit, can you please provide me whole flow .